# Is there a way to include multiple != operators?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a system that outputs invalid if a variable does not equal whole number or decimal number. The problem is, it outputs invalid when the variable is not equal to the first option instead of both options. Is there a fix for this?

I have tried making it an if statement as well as an else if statement instead of separating them with &&. It did not work.

```
if (user_input != "whole number") {
    std::cout << "\nInvalid";
    goto label1;
  }
  else if (user_input != "decimal number") {
    std::cout << "\nInvalid";
    goto label1;
  }
```

It outputs invalid is decimal number is inputted.

Comment: You need a compound conditional statement - join your two conditions in a single if statement with || which means or.

Comment: Generally it is poor practice to use goto statements as it makes code that can be very difficult to follow the logic of you have multiple gotos. Try writing your code without them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is that the system should output invalid if the variable does not equal "whole number" or "decimal number".

We can translate this directly into code. To emphasize how I translated the requirement, I'm using `and` and `or`, but the code would be identical if you wrote things the more conventional way, using `&&` for `and` and `||` for `or`.

```
if(user_input != "whole number" and user_input != "decimal number") 
{
    std::cout << "\nInvalid";
    goto label1;
}
```

Alternatively, we could write:

```
if (not (user_input == "whole number" or user_input == "decimal number")) 
{
    std::cout << "\nInvalid";
    goto label1;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it is correct, but I think you may want to mention that the *usual* way to write `or` is `||` and the *usual* way to write `and` is `&&`. Nothing wrong with using the [alternative operator names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative) - it's just "uncommon".  Same goes for `not` which is commonly written as `!`.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

A readable way to do this, with real code:

```
bool invalid = ((typeid(var) != typeid(int)) && (typeid(var) != typeid(double)));
if(invalid)
    std::cout << "Invalid !" << std::endl;
```

Hope it helps.